# Shortening an if statement

Tags: php

I'm doing this `if` statement in my code in order to add a banner `<div>` on the pages inside the check. How can I tidy this code up better?

```
    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($currentpage=="/" || $currentpage=="/en" || $currentpage=="/pl" || $currentpage=="/cz" || $currentpage=="/index.php" || $currentpage=="/index.php/" || $currentpage=="" || 
        $currentpage=="/en/index.php" || $currentpage=="/en/index.php/" ||  
        $currentpage=="/pl/index.php" || $currentpage=="/pl/index.php/" || 
        $currentpage=="/cz/index.php" || $currentpage=="/cz/index.php/" ||  
        $currentpage=="/flyeuro/en/index.php/" || $currentpage=="/flyeuro/en/index.php" || 
        $currentpage=="/flyeuro/pl/index.php/" || $currentpage=="/flyeuro/pl/index.php" ||
        $currentpage=="/flyeuro/cz/index.php/" || $currentpage=="/flyeuro/cz/index.php")
    {
```

Comment: why the minus. All I'm asking is how to tidy this messy code up, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Make a whitelist and loop over it / or use in_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<?php
    // add your all URLs to an array
    $urls = array("/en/index.php", "/en/index.php/", "/", "/en");

    if(in_array($currentpage, $urls)) {
        echo "It exists";
    } else {
        echo "It does not exist";
    }
?>
```